# Pandas: Timestamp in version 0.18.0 (with time zone)

Tags: python, pandas, timezone, timestamp

When I do

```
df[ts_col]
```

I see this output

```
Series: 0   2015-02-04 23:21:15-06:00
Name: Timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns, US/Central]
```

When I do

```
df[ts_col].apply(lambda x: x)
```

I see

```
Series: 0   2015-02-05 05:21:15
Name: Timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

When I do

```
df[ts_col].apply(lambda x: str(x))
```

I see

```
Series: 0    2015-02-05 05:21:15
Name: Timestamp, dtype: object
```

It makes no sense. Anyone can explain this? Specifically, I am interested in how do I extract the date `2015-02-04` from my timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known pandas issue, and looks like it's nearly fixed:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11800

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11757

For now, you can probably work around it with something like the last example:

```
In [182]: df["d"]
Out[182]:
0   2016-03-31 20:00:00-04:00
1   2016-03-31 21:00:00-04:00
2   2016-03-31 22:00:00-04:00
3   2016-03-31 23:00:00-04:00
4   2016-04-01 00:00:00-04:00
5   2016-04-01 01:00:00-04:00
Name: d, dtype: datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]

In [183]: df["d"].apply(lambda x: str(x))
Out[183]:
0    2016-04-01 00:00:00
1    2016-04-01 01:00:00
2    2016-04-01 02:00:00
3    2016-04-01 03:00:00
4    2016-04-01 04:00:00
5    2016-04-01 05:00:00
Name: d, dtype: object

In [184]: df["d"].astype(pd.datetime).apply(lambda x: x.date())
Out[184]:
0    2016-03-31
1    2016-03-31
2    2016-03-31
3    2016-03-31
4    2016-04-01
5    2016-04-01
Name: d, dtype: object
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Once you've got df["d"], it's a string that corresponds to a timestamp on 2016-04-01, all information on time zone is already lost at that point, no way to recover 2016-03-31.

Comment: I don't follow what you're saying. In the example I gave above, `Out[183]` shows the same incorrect result you're getting, but `Out[184]` gives you the non-timezone-aware date without first converting to UTC. `df["d"].astype(pd.datetime).apply(lambda x: x.date()).ix[0]` will then give back `datetime.date(2016, 3, 31)`, not a string.